# What 3d shape does water form when dropped on paper?

Tags: water, material-science, absorption

Say you have a stack of paper and you gently drop water on it (anything from 1 to 10 drops). How will water transfer through the paper ? What shape will it form ? What mathematical function best describes the difference of wet area between each layer of paper ?

I've been asking myself this question for a while and couldn't find an answer so I was wondering if there was some research about this or something specific I can search to learn about this before I try it myself.

Comment: What kind of paper? Copier paper behaves differently from cardstock which is different from fiberboard which is different from a paper napkin.

Comment: How does the type influences the result ? Is there a général rule that takes in a variable that paper types share ?